# Ripple effects not showing in my app

Tags: android, android-appcompat, ripple

I am creating an app extends `AppCompatActivity`. But I have a problem:

**Ripple effects not showing**

Am I doing wrong? Thank you

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Toolbar"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Toolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
</style>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing we need to do - is to create new ripple selector which will contain our old (slightly modified) holo selector:

drawabale/ripple_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:id="@android:id/mask"      
        android:drawable="@drawable/xyz"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/xyz"/>
</ripple>
```

The new ripple xml tag describes what our ripple should look like.

android:color - defines the color of ripple.

android:colorControlHighlight attribute in my theme to match my main accent color. In this way built-in ripple effects for default buttons will get the same color.

first item with id @android:id/mask defines the shape of my ripple. If we do not specify mask - shape will be determined by the shape of all other leyers.

Now we can use this drawable as background for Buttons etc.

**Edit:**

For simplicity create this in drawable and use as background in Buttons etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</ripple>
```

Comment: I not want to create a new ripple. I want to use default ripple effect

Comment: This is default ripple effect and only works with Lolipop and above.

Comment: @IMS @Dharmaraj use `?android:selectableItemBackground` for the default ripple.

Comment: is available for API versions >= 11